# list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas

Just started learning python. I am trying to open two files with these codes but getting error - list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Please help.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


real_gdp = pd.read_csv('GDPC1.csv',index_col=['DATE'],parse_dates=['DATE'])


real_gdppot = pd.read_excel('GDPPOT.xls','GDPPOT',skiprows=13,index_col=['DATE'])
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-5-dd98dfff0f6b>", line 14, in <module> index_col=['DATE'])

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 170, in       read_excel skip_footer=skip_footer, converters=converters, **kwds)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 418, in _parse_excel last = data[offset][col]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Have you bothered looking at the help for `read_csv` and the argument types it expects?

Comment: I think you can try `real_gdppot = pd.read_excel('GDPPOT.xls','GDPPOT',skiprows=13,index_col=None)` and then `real_gdppot = real_gdppot.set_index('DATE')`

Comment: @jezrael this worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) later:

```
real_gdppot = pd.read_excel('GDPPOT.xls','GDPPOT',skiprows=13,index_col=None)

real_gdppot = real_gdppot.set_index('DATE')
```